Prove that there always exist two distinct integers $0 < a, b <n$ for $n|(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+1)$ when $n$ is not a power of $3$
Prove that for any integer $n$ that is not a power of $3$, there exist two distinct integers $a$ and $b$ (both less than $n$) such that:
$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+1)≡0$ (mod $n$)
Sure! Here's a clearer and more polished version of your sentence:
I am stuck on a specific part of solving APMO 2014, Problem 3. I was attempting to approach the problem using this method.
I managed to prove that no solutions exist when $n$ is a power of $3$ (i.e.,$n=3^k$). But I failed to prove that there is always a solution when for all $n≠3^k$.
How I proved that there exists no solutions when $n=3^k$:
$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+1)≡0$ (mod $3^k$)
Either $(a-b)$ or $(a^2+ab+b^2+1)$ or both should be divisible by 3.
$(a^2+ab+b^2+1)≡(a-b)^2+1+3ab$
$(a-b)^2≡0$ or $1$ (mod $3$)
$(a-b)^2+1+3ab≡(0$ or $1) +1+0≡1$ or $2$
So $(a^2+ab+b^2+1)$ is never divisible by 3. Thus $3^k|(a-b)$
making $a≡b$ (mod $3^k$)
Since a and b are less than n,
$a=a$ mod $n$ and $b=b$ mod $n$
So $a≡b$ (mod $3^k$) means $a=b$
But that violates the fact that $a$ and $b$ are two distinct integers.
By this we can conclude $3^k$ can never be a solution for the above equation
Thank you for any input you provide.

Perhaps you're trying to solve the APMO problem using this approach? If so, you should make that clear, instead of saying that this is "inspired by" (which to me means that you've already done the APMO question and are trying to extend the result, so it's fair game for me to apply the APMO problem).

@CalvinLin Thank you for telling me this. I was indeed trying to solve the APMO with this approach. Sorry about my wording. I edited the question so everything is clearer.

Here are 2 approaches: 1/ Write it as $ (2a+b)^2 + 3b^2 + 4 \equiv 0$. Use PHP to show that solutions exist ( This is an immediate application of the high-power Cauchy-Davenport theorem, but I'm assuming you're not familiar with it.). $\quad$ 2/ If $x^3 + x$ is surjective on the reduced modulo set. Then show that  $ \prod x^2 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}, $ hence $ p = 3$.
